# Raw import in package doesn't work in Vite

Tags: vite

A bit simplified now, but I have the npm package `the-package` (in the `node_modules` folder) that contains the following:

- `the-package/code-file.js`
- `the-package/main-file.js`

In `the-package/main-file.js` I have this:

```js
import theCode from './code-file.js?raw' // Vite raw import here!

console.log(theCode)
```

When I import `the-package/main-file.js` in a Vite app, I get an error that looks something like this:

> node_modules/the-package/main-file.js: ERROR: No matching export in "node_modules/the-package/the-code.js?raw" for import "default"

Seems to me like Vite isn't doing its `?raw` magic in the package, so I guess that `?raw` import thing only works for files doing it in the Vite app by default. Can I somehow get it to work also for files in an npm package?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this solution](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/13493#issuecomment-1588791892) in a GitHub issue, and the suggested method there works for me too. `vite.config.js`:

```js
// ...
export default defineConfig({
    //...
    optimizeDeps: {
        esbuildOptions: {
            loader: {
                ".js": "text",
            },
        },
    },
    // ...
})
```

However, not sure if this will cause me any new problems in the future, so if a solution exists, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/10839#issuecomment-1345193175

> You can't use Vite specific features within third-party packages. Vite will ignore them which causes the invalid URLs. If you want to process them by Vite, you need to add the package to `optimizeDeps.exclude`

Using `optimizeDeps.exclude` to exclude (in my case) `the-package` seems to work. If I understand [Dependency Pre-Bundling](https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html#dependency-pre-bundling)  correct, it says:

> Dependency pre-bundling only applies in development mode[...]

I hope this means that (in my case) `the-package` is still optimized by Vite when building for production.

Not sure if this is the best solution, so if someone knows, tell me, please.