# Vite and/or SvelteKit is failing to load a web worker in a module from the main app in dev, though it works in preview

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit, web-worker

I wrote a [little Svelte module](https://github.com/jswest/midsommer) called `midsommer`, which uses a web worker to generate Self-Organizing Maps. My worker import:

```js
import { onMount } from "svelte";
import workerUrl from "$lib/workers/worker.js?worker&url";

let worker;
onMount(() => {
  worker = new Worker(workerUrl, { type: "module" });
})
```

This works very well when I'm running midsommer as a stand-alone component, in both `npm run dev` and `npm run preview`.

When I import the midsommer component into my main library, though, it fails when I run `npm run dev` with this error:

```
No matching export in "node_modules/midsommer/dist/workers/worker.js?worker&url" for import "default"
```

Confusingly, when I run `npm run build` and `npm run preview` in my main library, it works just fine.

Previously, I was getting worker in midsommer like this:

```js
worker = new Worker(new URL("./../workers/worker.js", import.meta.url), {
  type: "module",
});
```

This was also failing on dev—though not on preview—with the error:

```
Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "../classes/som.js" from "node_modules/.vite/workers/worker.js?type=module&worker_file". Does the file exist?
```

The file does exist at the correct path in the midsommer directory tree, but doesn't exist in the `node_modules/.vite` location.

To recap:

- Importing and using the worker in the midsommer library works both ways I tried.
- Importing and using the worker in the client library works both ways I tried, if I'm running `npm run preview`.
- Importing and using the worker in the client library fails in different ways both ways I tried, if I'm running `npm run dev`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured this out. I needed to exclude "midsommer" from "optimizeDeps" in the vite config of my client library, like so:

```js
import { sveltekit } from "@sveltejs/kit/vite";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    optimizeDeps: {
        exclude: ["midsommer"],
    },
});
```

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77430426/raw-import-in-package-doesnt-work-in-vite/77432729#77432729), which is about `?raw` extensions, not `?module` ones.

Hoo boy, did I burn a lot of time on this... And I'm not sure this is the perfect solution, since any client app will have to add this snippet.